# Does Dokan/Dokan.NET (not) support synchronous I/O?

Tags: c#, file, io, dokan

I created a virtual drive in C# using the Dokan(.NET) library, and it's working quite well.

However, when I try to read a file from the drive in another application I get an exception whenever using operations that read synchronously, like `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(...)`.

The text of the exception is: "Handle does not support synchronous operations. The parameters to the FileStream constructor may need to be changed to indicate that the handle was opened asynchronously".

So if I am interpreting this correctly, .NET apparently tries to read the entire content of the file in a single synchronous operation, but Dokan does not seem to allow that.

But when using a method like `ReadAllText` I don't really have any control over the way the `FileStream` is constructed (isn't that the whole point of that method, after all, simply get the file content without having to bother with Streams and Readers and Buffers and whatnot?).

Can I get Dokan to support synchronous I/O access on it's file handles somehow? Or do I have to somehow live with the fact that synchronous operations are just not possible on Dokan-hosted files (and hope that no application that might ever have to work on my virtual drive depends on them)?

Comment: Do you managed to solve this. I am new to Dokan. Newest is currently 0.6

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you need synchronicity in the file read? You could do an async read to a stream, and handle when it finishes via a callback.

This has a good presentation/tutorial on different ways to do async file i/o:

[msdn async file io](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc337900.aspx)

Comment: The type of access is not up to me. I just wanted to provide a virtual file system that anyone could access. If that access happens though, for example, a .NET application written by someone else, who happens to use the `ReadAllText` method to read a file from the virtual drive, there's not much I can do. The file system should just be able to support any kind of access that arbitrary applications might be using.